# Calling a JavaScript Function on document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typescript

I'm trying to set the value of a paragraph element in HTML using JavaScript once the document has finished loading, but it doesn't seem to be working.

From the picture with red underlines, I have indicated:

1) that I have already included the jQuery library from Google's CDN.

2) that I have already "linked" (not sure what the right word is) my .ts file with my HTML file.

3) that I have already set the id of a paragraph element to "filler"

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>

    <link   rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">        <!-- Makes me host Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>        <!-- Not sure if I'll need this -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/4c5e04f914.js"></script>
    <script src="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&APPID={178e8d4180edebe4e2c02fcad75b72fd}"></script>
    <script src="../js/script.ts"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1 id="filler">Weather Wizard</h1>
        <p>Finding your local weather!</p>
        <!-- Your current location is: -->
        <p id="currentCity"></p>
    </div>
</body>
</head>
```

On the script.ts file, I have:

4) called my getLocation() method inside the document.ready callback function

5) tried to set the html of element with id="filler" to something

```
$(document).ready(function () {
getLocation();

/**
 * called when the user clicks the "find weather" button
 * get the user's current location, shows an error if the browser does not support Geolocation
 */
function getLocation(): void {
    document.getElementById("filler").innerHTML = "is this showing up?";
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationSuccess, locationError);
    } else {
        showError("Your browser does not support Geolocation!");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I load the HTML file in my browser, the text with id="filler" doesn't get changed to "is this showing up?"

I've also tried making something similar on repl.it and it works as intended there.

https://repl.it/@jonathanwangg/test

What am I doing wrong / missing?

Comment: Please post the code and not pictures of your code.

Comment: You should also tag typescript instead of just javascript

Comment: I've changed the images to code, added the tags. Hope that helps.

Comment: Looks like you probably have console errors.  Check for some by hitting Ctrl+j in you browser.

Comment: @DavidThomas, I'm following the syntax for return types in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html . If you CTRL+F "Typing the function", they have an example where they are doing the same thing as me.

Comment: @earl3s, I checked the browser's console and I am getting this back:


forecast Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)


bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at bootstrap.min.js:6


forecast Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)index.html:1 


Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:63342/WeatherWizard/src/js/script.ts' because its MIME type ('application/octet-stream') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: @Jonathan: I stand corrected, thank you! Also: *ewww, TypeScript...* ;)

Comment: @DavidThomas So should the :void be removed still even though it's the correct syntax?

Comment: I don't think so; but since it seems to be a shorthand for telling TypeScript what the return value of the function should be, I don't know that it's required, so maybe you could remove to test? Sadly I don't know TypeScript well enough to make any truly useful suggestions. Removing that part of the function declaration was based on my knowledge of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser doesn't understand typescript. It complains about the `: void` part. You'll have to compile your files to regular javascript or just write javascript. Remove the `: void` and it should works

Also you shouldn't load the openweathcermap api as a script src. You are loading jQuery so that means you can use the jQuery ajax function to do an API call.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the typescript thing.

Also, why shouldn't I load openweathermap as a script src? Any benefits or consequences of using jQuery AJAX instead?

Comment: The openweathermap resolves in an Object. You would have no way of manipulating the object received from the `<script src='open....'></script>` while AJAX allows you to fully control it. Like `var obj = ajaxResponse[2]` or whatever.

Comment: I'm try to use certain values in the JSON response that I'm getting back from calling their API. What I'm using currently is jQuery's $.get(). Is this what you mean?

Comment: As long as you are getting a response from the api you are good to go